# How to check MongoDB to see if item already exist in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've gotten my items into a collection in my database as an array of objects. Now I've noticed that the items are being added every time the server restarts, resulting in 6 instead of 3 products. How would I check the database to see if an item already exists within a collection so it's not duplicated? At the moment I'm getting  'ReferenceError: title is not defined'

Product.js (Model)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    product_id: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
    },
    imagepath: {
        type: String
        // required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String
        // required: true
    },    
    description: {
        type: String
        // required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number
        // required: true
    },
});
```

Product-seeder.js(populates products collection)

```
module.exports = Product = mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema);
const Product = require('../models/Product');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const products = [
    new Product ({
        imagePath: '../client/src/Components/Layout/Media/armadillo.png',
        title: 'Pangolin',
        description: "This is a pangolin",
        price: 15000
    }),
    new Product ({
        imagePath: '../client/src/Components/Layout/Media/croc.png',
        title: 'Cuban corcodile',
        description: "This is a croc",
        price: 15000
    }),
    new Product ({
        imagePath: '../client/src/Components/Layout/Media/monkey.png',
        title: 'Golden Gibbon',
        description: "This is a monkey",
        price: 15000
    })
];

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    Product.findOne({title: title})
    .then(products => {
        if (!product) {
        products[i].save();
        } 
    }); 
}
mongoose.disconnect();
```

Comment: You getting reference error bcuz title is not defined in `Product.findOne({title: title})`. You should change `title: title` to `title: products[i].title` in Product.findOne()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did two mistakes in your query.

> Use  `products[i].title` instead of `title`.
>
> Change Products with `results` or any other variable.

```
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    console.log(products[i]);
    Product.findOne({title: products[i].title}) //products[i].title 
    .then(results => { //update products with results
      console.log(results)
        if (!results) {
        products[i].save();
        } 
    }); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can go about this; use the original array of objects instead of the Mongoose documents with **[`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)**.

**[`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)** allows you to send multiple `insertOne`, `updateOne`, `updateMany`, `replaceOne`, `deleteOne`, and/or `deleteMany` operations to the MongoDB server in one command, instead of the current set up where you are sending multiple commands to the server with a for loop. In this instance you need multiple **[`updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#updateone-and-updatemany)** operations with the update operation as **[`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert)**.

Take for instance, suppose you have an array

```
const products = [
    {
        imagePath: '../client/src/Components/Layout/Media/armadillo.png',
        title: 'Pangolin',
        description: "This is a pangolin",
        price: 15000
    },
    {
        imagePath: '../client/src/Components/Layout/Media/croc.png',
        title: 'Cuban corcodile',
        description: "This is a croc",
        price: 15000
    },
    {
        imagePath: '../client/src/Components/Layout/Media/monkey.png',
        title: 'Golden Gibbon',
        description: "This is a monkey",
        price: 15000
    }
];
```

You can set up your **[`updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#updateone-and-updatemany)** operations list which can be of the following form

```
[
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter" : <document>,
         "update" : <document>,
         "upsert" : <boolean>
      }
   }
]
```

Map the products array to the above as

```
const ops = products.map(product => (
    { "updateOne": {
        "filter": { "title": product.title },
        "update": { "$setOnInsert": product },
        "upsert": true
    } }
))
```

You can then apply **[`bulkWrite()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)** on the above as:

```
Product.bulkWrite(ops).then(result => console.log(result))
```

In the above, if a matching document exists, the update with **[`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert)** does nothing as the update operation does not result in an insert, having found a document that matches the query.

---

Should you go with the original implementation, you need to fix the query and then build up the promises in the for loop as:

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    const productPromise = Product.findOne({
        title: products[i].title // <- fixed
    }).then(product => {
        if (!product) { // <-- fixed
            return products[i].save();
        } 
    });
    promises.push(productPromise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(result => console.log(result));
```